# Is tips halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

Assalamualaikum!
My question is,  * Is tips halal or haram? In details,  I'm working in a 4* hotel, There are so many guests comes from outside to stay in our hotel,  When they arrive in hotel I take there bags to there room. And I show them everything,  like Ac, tv etc operatint system.  Sometimes they become happy and pay me extra money which we call tips. And some times I open door for the guest and they give me tips. is this halal? Some times I just say hello to ssomeone and they pay me money, is it haram or halal money? My company paying me monthly basis salary.  If guest gives me money, that's for me. Company they don't have any problem about this tips. What islam says please make me clear soon. Thank you